# Getting gmail public profile picture from gmail address

Tags: android, google-api, gmail

For my Android application I need to get the Gmail profile picture from a given Gmail address. And I don't want to force the user to sign in because I just need only the profile picture. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Google+ ID to get the profile picture using an email.

You can try to search for the user's photo via [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) but that's just scraping the bottom of the barrel.

Just go with Google+ sign in with very minimal permissions or let users upload a photo.